# Pass directive event from child to parent component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, directive

I have a parent component (sidebar) and a child component (menu)

I have a custom directive that detects if a click is made outside the element:

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickedOutside]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ClickedOutsideDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @Output() public clickedOutside = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event: any) {
    if (!this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      this.clickedOutside.emit(true);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event'])
  onEscapeKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.clickedOutside.emit(true);
  }
}
```

In the menu component I am emitting an event:

```
 @Output() menuClosed = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

In the menu template, I am applying the directive to the div of the menu and emitting true when a an outside click is made.

```
<div
  appClickedOutside
  (clickedOutside)="menuClosed.emit(true)"
></div>
```

In the sidebar component (parent) I am receiving this and closing the menu:

```
onMenuClosed(isClosed: boolean) {
    if (isClosed && this.isMenuOpen) {
      this.isMenuOpen = false;
    }
  }
```

However, when I click the button in the parent that opens the menu, it is not working anymore:

```
<button
      (click)="toggleMenu()"
    ></button>
```

toggleMenu is:

```
 toggleMenu() {
    this.isMenuOpen = !this.isMenuOpen;
  }
```

What is wrong with this implementation?

Comment: please share a minimal code stackblitz where the issue happens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE:

After user share the minimal reproducible stackblitz, I added the class `ignore-click` on  the button, then on the directive the below condition ignored the button click!

```
    ...
    if (
     !(
        this.el.nativeElement?.contains(event.target) ||
        event.target?.classList?.contains('ignore-click')
      )
    ) {
      this.clickedOutside.emit(true);
    }
    ...
```

#### Full Code

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { MenuComponent } from './app/menu/menu.component';
import { ClickOutsideDirective } from './app/click-outside.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [MenuComponent, ClickOutsideDirective],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu-container">
      <button (click)="toggleMenu()" class="ignore-click">Toggle menu</button>
      @if(isMenuOpen) {
      <app-menu appClickOutside (clickedOutside)="isMenuOpen=false;"/>
    }
    </div>
</div>
  `,
  styles: `
    .menu-container {
      position: relative
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
  `,
})
export class App {
  isMenuOpen = false;

  toggleMenu() {
    this.isMenuOpen = !this.isMenuOpen;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

directive

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickOutside]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @Output() public clickedOutside = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event: any) {
    if (
      !(
        this.el.nativeElement?.contains(event.target) ||
        event.target?.classList?.contains('ignore-click')
      )
    ) {
      this.clickedOutside.emit(true);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event'])
  onEscapeKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.clickedOutside.emit(true);
  }
}
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rrycez?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fclick-outside.directive.ts)

---

Its happening because the button click will also be considers as an outside click!!

Please pass in the button ref also to the directive and ignore the click if it originates from the button!

```
<button #buttonRef> this opens the menu!</button>
<div
  appClickedOutside
  [buttonRef]="buttonRef"
  (clickedOutside)="menuClosed.emit(true)"
></div>
```

Then the directive can be changed to

```
import { 
  Input,
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickedOutside]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ClickedOutsideDirective {
  @Input() buttonRef: ElementRef<any>;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @Output() public clickedOutside = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event: any) {
    if (!(this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target) &&
          this.el.nativeElement === this.buttonRef.nativeElement)) { // <-changed here
      this.clickedOutside.emit(true);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event'])
  onEscapeKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.clickedOutside.emit(true);
  }
}
```

Since there is no stackblitz its difficult to debug the issue.

---

There is no need to even pass in the button. You can define a class like `do-not-notice-this` and then check if the event target does not have this class!

```
<button class="do-not-notice-this"> this opens the menu!</button>
<div
  appClickedOutside
  (clickedOutside)="menuClosed.emit(true)"
></div>
```

the directive can be

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickedOutside]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ClickedOutsideDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @Output() public clickedOutside = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event: any) {
    if (!(this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target) &&
          this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains('do-not-notice-this')) { // <-changed here
      this.clickedOutside.emit(true);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event'])
  onEscapeKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.clickedOutside.emit(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that but it's still not working. The only working solution is to put the directive on the menu container (which includes both the toggle button and the menu). However, I only want to register clicks outside the menu itself and not outside the menu container.

Comment: Here is a minimal example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-eriqwv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fclick-outside.directive.ts

Comment: The issue with the above solution is that I'm applying the directive on the menu component not the menu container so this `this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains('do-not-notice-this'))` will not work because the `nativeElement` does not contain the toggle button and its class `do-not-notice-this`

Comment: @SevenSouls Thank you for the stackblitz, updated my answer!

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate that. Eventually, I added `event.stopPropagation()` to the toggleMenu handler. This solved the issue without adding anything to the directive. But your solution works too.

Comment: @SevenSouls You're welcome, whatever works is good :)